# Parsing multi-array JSON? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

How would I parse this multi-level JSON to get title?

```
{"query":{"search":[{"ns":0,"title":"Getfenv"}]}}
```

Comment: query.search[0].title

Comment: like you would any other multi-level object/array in JS. just because it's json doesn't means it's magically something other than javascript. the `js` in json stands for `(j)ava(s)cript`, after all...

Answer (score 1):

```
obj.query.search[0].title
```

you can try out this